# Flex AIR play AAC audio file from local disk

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

I would like to play AAC audio format file from local disk. I got example to play through netstreaming but I need to play it from local disk. I got an example to play mp3 file from local disk using Sound class.

For reference:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashmediaserver/articles/audio_playlist_app_05.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
<fx:Script>
    [Bindable]
    public var aacUrl:String = "http://amp-mp3.s3.amazonaws.com/48c30f3b-e1ed-4f04-a58b-4806fcc27416?Expires=1602460800&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJU2DNJUS3E3D36BA&Signature=h6HUy35V1QOi56fm9kakaCRjma4%3D";


    protected function playButton_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        videoPlayer.play();
    }

</fx:Script>
<s:VGroup>
    <s:VideoPlayer id="videoPlayer" height="200" width="300" source="{aacUrl}" autoPlay="false"/>   
    <s:HGroup width="100%">
        <s:Label text="URL:" />
        <s:TextInput id="mediaUrlTextInput" width="100%" text="@{aacUrl}" />
        <s:Button id="playButton" label="Play" click="playButton_clickHandler(event)" />
    </s:HGroup>

</s:VGroup>
```